# Complex Nested SUM / Sub-Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

**UPDATED** with sample data etc.

I am a bit over my head on this complex query.  Some background:  This is a rails app and I have `expenditures` model which has many `expenditure_items` which each has an amount column - these all sum up to a total for the related expenditure.

A given `expenditure` can be an Order which then can have multiple (or single or nil) related Invoice `expenditures`.  I am looking for a single query that jives me all the orders which have total invoices and identify those that have invoices totalling more than a threshold (in my case 10%).

I get the idea from my searching that I need a sub-select here but I can't sort it out.  I apologize as raw SQL is not my wheel house - normal Rails Active Record calls meet 99% of my needs.

Sample Data:

```
=> SELECT * FROM expenditures WHERE id = 17;
 id  | category       | parent_id
-----+----------------+----------
  17 | purchase_order | 

=> SELECT * FROM expenditures_items WHERE expenditure_id = 17;
 id  | amount
-----+-------------
   1 | 1000.00
   2 | 2000.00
```

I need to obtain the SUM ( expenditures.amount ) in my result - the original order of $3,000.00.

Related Expenditures (invoices)

```
=> SELECT * FROM expenditures WHERE category = 'invoice', parent_id = 17;
 id  | category       | parent_id
-----+----------------+----------
  46 | invoice        | 17 
  88 | invoice        | 17 

=> SELECT * FROM expenditures_items WHERE expenditure_id IN (46, 88) ;
 id  | amount   | expenditure_id
-----+----------+---------------
  23 |  500.00  | 46
  24 | 1000.00  | 46
  78 |  550.00  | 88
  79 | 1100.00  | 88
```

Order 17 has two invoices (46 & 88) totalling $3,150.00 - this is the SUM of all the invoice expenditure_item amounts.

In the end I am looking for the SQL that gets me something like this:

```
=> SELECT * FROM expenditures WHERE category = 'purchase_order';
 id  | category       | expenditure_total | invoice_total | percent
-----+----------------+-------------------+---------------+---------
  17 | purchase_order | 3000.00           | 3150.00       | 5
  45 | purchase_order | 4000.00           | 3000.00       | -25
  75 | purchase_order | 7000.00           | 7000.00       | 0
  99 | purchase_order | 10000.00          | 11100.00      | 11
```

percent is invoice_total / expenditure_total - 1.

I also need to (perhaps a HAVING clause) filter out only the results that have a percent > a threshold (say 10).

From all my searching this seems to be a sub query along with some joins but I am lost at this point.

**UPDATED Further**

I had another look - this is close:

```
SELECT DISTINCT expenditures.*, SUM( invoice_items.amount ) as invoiced_total FROM "expenditures" JOIN expenditures AS invoices ON invoices.category = 'invoice' AND expenditures.id = CAST( invoices.ancestry AS INT) JOIN expenditure_items ON expenditure_items.expenditure_id = expenditures.id JOIN expenditure_items AS invoice_items ON invoice_items.expenditure_id = invoices.id WHERE "expenditures"."category" IN ($1, $2) GROUP BY expenditures.id HAVING (( SUM( invoice_items.amount ) / SUM( expenditure_items.amount ) ) > 1.1 )  [["category", "work_order"], ["category", "purchase_order"]]
```

Here is the odd thing - the `invoiced_total` in the select works.  I get the proper amounts as per my example.  The issue seems to be in my HAVING where it only pulls the SUM on the first invoice.

UPDATE 3

Soooooo close:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    expenditures.*, 
    ( SELECT 
          SUM(expenditure_items.amount) 
      FROM expenditure_items 
      WHERE expenditure_items.expenditure_id = expenditures.id ) AS order_total, 
    ( SELECT 
          SUM(expenditure_items.amount) 
      FROM expenditure_items 
      JOIN expenditures invoices ON expenditure_items.expenditure_id = invoices.id 
           AND CAST (invoices.ancestry AS INT)  = expenditures.id ) AS invoice_total 
FROM "expenditures" 
INNER JOIN "expenditure_items" ON "expenditure_items"."expenditure_id" = "expenditures"."id" 
WHERE "expenditures"."category" IN ("work_order", "purchase_order")
```

The only thing I can't get is eliminate the expenditures that either have no invoices or that are over my 10% rule.  The first was in my old solution with the original join - I can't seem to figure out how to sum on that join data.

Comment: Please show us your table structure, some sample data sets and the expected output.

Comment: I think this is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1ec89f15d9925dd853a8c1a579348a31)

I am sure, there is a better solution, but this one should work:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        e.id,
        e.category,
        COALESCE(parent_id, e.id) AS parent_id,
        ei.amount
    FROM 
        expenditures e 
    JOIN
        expenditures_items ei ON e.id = ei.expenditure_id
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE category = 'purchase_order') AS expentiture_total,
        SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE category = 'invoice') AS invoice_total
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            parent_id AS id,
            category,
            SUM(amount) AS amount
        FROM cte
        GROUP BY (parent_id, category)
    ) s
    GROUP BY id
)
SELECT 
    *,
    (invoice_total/expentiture_total - 1) * 100 AS percent
FROM
    cte2
```

The first CTE joins the both tables. The `COALESCE()` function mirrors the id as parent_id if the record has none (if `category = 'purchase_order'`). This can be used to do one single `GROUP` on this id and the category.

This is done within the second CTE (most inner subquery). [Btw: I choose the CTE variant because I find it much more readable. In this case you could do all steps as subqueries of course.] This group sums up the different categories for each (`parent_`)`id`.

The outer subquery is doing a pivot. It shifts the different records per category into your expected result with the help of a `GROUP BY` and the `FILTER` clause (Have a look at this step in the fiddle to understand it). Don't worry about the `SUM()` function here. Because of the `GROUP BY`, one aggregation function is necessary, but it does nothing, because the grouping has been already done.

Last step is calculating the percent value out of the pivoted table.

Comment: I was typing an update as you posted - have a look while I test drive you answer.

Comment: I have seen this. I will check it tomorrow, it's late right now :)

Comment: That does work but I was looking for something like `SELECT expenditures.*, expenditure_total, invoice_total, percent FROM expenditures..`.  I want the individual expenditure records PLUS that added bit of aggregate data.

Comment: I did some reading on CTE (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/queries-with.html).  Honestly I had never seen these before.  Starting to wrap my head around them.  I need to see if I can make this work in my Rails app.

Comment: 1. The CTE is not quite necessary here, it's just for readability. The same can be achieved by simply using these statements as subquery: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6608d8d32a9578f2568396de7b7ee889, which, in fact, is even slightly faster (have a look at the costs): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4a6d81c7c7405c762001092ac841a109

Comment: 2. Your (UPDATE 3) way, in contrast, is extremely slow because of the multiple calls of the same table which should be avoided every time. The joins are expensive too an the DISTINCT as well. So your query is 10x slower then my CTE query (only one small join, calling the table only one time, no distinct): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0847928811933857ceb3e035d1c29460

Comment: The subquery with the first SUM() aggregation can be left out because of the SUM() aggregation of the pivot table (but it is slightliy slower for some reasons: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a508ff9a8136587c5dc3bb112b57e108). The last subquery can be left out if you would calculate the SUM() twice for the percent: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=71d1f383ab1629f645eb236958299907. Redundant code execution, of course, is more expensive: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e33b3c48193814a2b0818e1e2889a73b

Comment: It does but in my case (a Rails app) you build a SQL query like this: Expenditure.where(id: 17) => "SELECT * FROM expenditures WHERE id = 17".  The Rails Active Record system builds and executes that query for you.  Now that being said I bet I can build these CTE queries but the easy way is to start with Expenditure.where(category: 'invoice'....).  I would like to make this work in Rails also, post the work around then accept the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197229/discussion-between-dan-tappin-and-s-man).